# How to prove that a real number is the lower integral of the function based on the following assumption?

Tags: calculus, integration, supremum-and-infimum

Let $M$ be a real number,

If $1.\ \forall\epsilon\gt0,$ there exists a partition $P$ of $[a,b]$ such that $M-\epsilon \lt L_f(M)\le M.$

$\ \  \ 2.\ L_f(M)\le M$ for every partition P of $[a,b]  $ .

How to prove $M=\underline{I}_a^b(f)$

In my opinion, since we can use contradiction to prove the first condition, $M$ has to be least upper bound for the condition to work, but I don't know how to formally prove it. So if $M$ is certainly a least upper bound, then by the second condition, we confirm that $M$ it the least upper bound for all lower sum and thus is the lower integral. Could someone help with the proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First some clarification.  For a (nonempty) real set, if there is any upper bound at all, there is then a least upper bound (aka supremum), one and only one.

You're trying to take the least upper bound of the set of $L_f(P)$'s over all partitions $P$.  Your first condition is that you can find an $L_f(P)$ which is $> M-\epsilon$ for positive $\epsilon$.  That means that, for any positive $\epsilon$, the number $M-\epsilon$ is *not* an upper bound of the set of all $L_f(P)$'s.

The second condition is that $M$ *is* an upper bound of the set of all $L_f(P)$'s.

Putting the two things together, $M$ is the *least* upper bound of that set.  Anything less than $M$ and it's not an upper bound.

Comment: That clears my confusion, thanks so much